# How to implement two countdown timers alternatively in Android

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have implemented one counter and onFinish() of first counter,I started second counter but the first counter not able to finish.Text "Bye Guyz" remain for some time so how to finish the text.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.!!!

**Code :-**

```
counter= new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    if (count == 0) {
                        tv.setText("First counter");
                        tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        tv2.setText("Hello Guyz");
                    }
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    if(!flag) {
                        tv2.setText("Bye Guyz");
                        count = 0;
                        try {
                            counter.cancel();
                        }catch (Exception e){}
                    }
                    else if(flag) {
                       counter1 = new CountDownTimer(9000, 1000) {
                            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                flag = false;
                                tv.setText("Second counter");
                        tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        tv2.setText("Hello Girls");
                                count = 0;
                            }

                            public void onFinish() {
                                tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                tv2.setText("Bye Girls");
                                count = 0;
                            }
                        }.start();
```

Comment: The code is complete ? The `else if(flag)` is not closed.

Comment: Some variable make me wander, where is `counter` and `flag` coming from ?

Answer (score 1):

- Did you "debug" the code to be sure the code is arriving to `counter1 = new CountDownTimer(9000, 1000)`?
- Are you sure when the first `counter` arrives to `onFinish()` the `flag` variable is true?
- Why do you call `counter.cancel()` in `onFinish()` when obviously the counter is already over?

`public void onFinish() {
  if(!flag) {
   tv2.setText("Bye Guyz");
    count = 0;
    try {
        counter.cancel();
    }catch (Exception e){}
}`

Answer (score 0):

If you say your tv2 displays "Bye Guyz" it means that  your flag is set to false, so the "else if" part is not being executed. onFinish() is only executed once, so you need to make sure the flag is set for true to start the second counter.

Also you shouldn't cancel your counter in onFinish() because it's already finished.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my alternative is as follows

Create the custom `Counter`extending `Thread`

```
class Counter extends Thread {
    private long timeOne, timeTwo;
    private OnCounterFinishedListener mCounterFinishedListener;
    private Thread t;
    Activity activity = null;


    Counter(Context context){
        t = new Thread(this);
        activity = (Activity)context;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            sleep(timeOne);
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mCounterFinishedListener.firstCounterFinished();
                }
            });

            sleep(timeTwo);
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mCounterFinishedListener.secondCounterFinished();
                }
            });

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

     void setTimes(long timeOne, long timeTwo){
        this.timeOne = timeOne;
        this.timeTwo = timeTwo;
    }

    public void start(OnCounterFinishedListener listener){
        mCounterFinishedListener = listener;
        t.start();
    }




    interface OnCounterFinishedListener{
        void firstCounterFinished();
        void secondCounterFinished();
    }
}
```

Then inside your main thread you can start this counter as

```
final Counter counter = new Counter(this);
counter.setTimes(5000, 5000);
counter.start(new Counter.OnCounterFinishedListener() {
    @Override
    public void firstCounterFinished() {
        // Update your first TextView
    }

    @Override
    public void secondCounterFinished() {
        // Update your second TextView
    }
});
```